# Unable to download PDF file, fetched from Sql Database.Bytes value has been fetched, Function doesn't through any error, But PDF is not downloaded

Tags: model-view-controller

I am unable to download a PDF file, fetched from Sql Database. Bytes value has been fetched, Function doesn't throw any error, but the PDF is not downloaded.

Code:

```
    public ActionResult PrintPDF(string projectSelection)
    {


        byte[] extract = (byte[])_selectionManager.FindPdf();

        MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfStream.Write(extract, 0, extract.Length);
        pdfStream.Position = 0;
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=form.pdf");

        return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the file content as bytes, why converting it to stream ?

Please check if this works

```
byte[] extract = (byte[])_selectionManager.FindPdf();
return File(
    extract, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "form.pdf");
```

Comment: Function will execute, but PDF will not be downloaded...!

Comment: check the network tab in developer console, it should download the file, unless some antivirus or settings prevents